# Can you call a named template inside a CVT in XSLT3?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

My input looks as following:

```
<party>
    <name>Jessica's 18th birthday</name>
    <participants>
        <participant>
            <name>Jessica</name>
        </participant>
        <participant>
            <name>Aron</name>
        </participant>
        <participant>
            <name>Steve</name>
        </participant>
    </participants>
</party>
```

I have created a utility named template which given a `party` element converts all the participant names to a comma-separated string:

```
<xsl:template name="list-participants">
    <xsl:param name="party"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$party/participants/participant ! name" separator=";"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT3 here. I am using so-called content value templates (CVT) in my stylesheet, as this makes things much more readable:

```
name: {name}
```

instead of

```
name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
```

Now my question here is: is it possible to use these `{...}` expansions here as well to execute/call the `list-participants` template? Basically, I would like to do something as following:

```
<xsl:template match="party">
    The following persons will be present at the party: {list-participants(party=.)}
</xsl:template>
```

Here, `.` refers to the current `party` element. (The above is pseudo-core, hopefully it helps to make my question more clear and does not confuse quick readers.)

You could say I want to do a function call, as seen in procedural languages.

Is this (in some way) possible in XSLT3?

Comment: It might be that you want to implement the named template as a named function instead and then you can call it of course in a text value template with e.g. `{mf:list-participants(.)}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you use a function, rather than a named template

```
<xsl:template match="party">
    <xsl:text>The following persons will be present at the party:{my:list-participants(.)}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="my:list-participants">
    <xsl:param name="party"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$party/participants/participant/name" separator=";"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Where the namespace prefix `my` can be defined as to how you like.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKN

Comment: That is neat! I did not know you could define functions like that. I have been writing named templates, but they "feeled" wrong. This makes much more sense. Thank you Tim, very much appreciated.

Comment: Also, these fiddles are quite neat as well. I will be using them to experiment and in my questions in the future.